# XAMPP и двойные кавычки

Tags: xampp

XAMPP наотрез отказывается воспринимать двойные кавычки, на конструкцию типа -

```
$test =
        "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">" .
        "<HTML>" .
        "<HEAD>" .
        "<TITLE>Test</TITLE>" .
        "</HTML>";
```

Вывод -

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
> '>' in [path] on line [number]

Возможно как либо исправить ситуацию не правя сам код?

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаком с хampp, но мне кажется, что это скорее всего проблема в php.
Попробуйте следующее:

```
$test = <<<HERE
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
...
HERE;
```

Comment: В проекте где эта ошибка возникает достаточно много кода, и, хотелось бы обойтись без его правки.